# Why can the Rust compiler infer types on separated lines but not if combined into one line?

Tags: types, syntax, rust, compiler-construction, type-inference

Why is this allowed:

```
let payload = "key1=value1";
let value: Vec<&str> = payload.split("=").collect();
let value = value[1];
println!("value is {:?}", value);
```

But not this:

```
let payload = "key1=value1";
let value: Vec<&str> = payload.split("=").collect()[1];
println!("value is {:?}", value);
```

This results in the error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:3:47
  |
3 |     let value: Vec<&str> = payload.split("=").collect()[1];
  |                                               ^^^^^^^
  |                                               |
  |                                               cannot infer type for type parameter `B` declared on the method `collect`
  |                                               help: consider specifying the type argument in the method call: `collect::<B>`
  |
  = note: type must be known at this point
```

Aren't the two equivalent? They are the same *tokens to be parsed*, compiler-wise, just split into different lines.

I don't understand which extra info is present in the first syntax to make the inference possible.

Perhaps this is not about inference not possible, as the compiler warns, but it's not allowed due Rust syntax, convention, etc.?

I am trying to understand *why* is not possible for the compiler to infer it (i.e. logically missing information? just due convention?) and not *how* to fix this specific case.

Thinking about this at the compiler/parser level,

*expression*: `let value: Vec<&str> = payload.split("=").collect()`
*suffix*: `[1]`

A (acceptable):

```
(expression)
(expression')(suffix)
```

B (not acceptable):

```
(expression)(suffix)
```

Considering that `expression'` basically adds `value = value`, which is a tautology and does not add any new information,

If `expression` and `expression'` have the same extent of information, why is B not valid for the compiler? Why can't it infer the same thing in B if there is no new information?

I am questioning the 'cannot infer' part specifically and not that 'should be XX due Rust YY syntax/convention').

Is this just a compiler limitation or intentional error to enforce legibility, or there is unique information being added from one case to another? (logically distinct scenarios).

Answer (score 3):

The first snippet,

```
let value: Vec<&str> = payload.split("=").collect();
let value = value[1];
```

is saying to collect an iterator into a vector (of `&str`s) and then assign the element at the index `1` to `value` (which would be a `&str`). Note that the first `value` is shadowed by the second (they have different types, so you need to do this if you want them to have the same name).

Due in part to the type annotation, the single line version is saying something different.

```
let value: Vec<&str> = payload.split("=").collect()[1];
```

This is saying to collect an iterator into ...something... and index it at `1` and the resulting type should be `Vec<&str>`. Now, since any number of types could potentially generate `Vec<&str>` when indexing (it could be `Vec<Vec<&str>>`, `HashMap<usize, Vec<&str>>` or even some type defined in this project or a dependency), Rust doesn't try to guess here. Since it has no idea what type to collect into, it gives up and returns that error.

To do this correctly (in one line), you'd likely want to use the ol' turbofish syntax to indicate what sort of type you want to collect into.

```
let value = payload.split("=").collect::<Vec<_>>()[1];
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f5e3da0473a4c2ca88c7eeb274a52a59)

Note that the type of the elements of the `Vec` is known since it's just whatever the type of the elements of the iterator is. That's why we can use `Vec<_>` to let the compiler infer the correct type.

One more thing. To be more idiomatic, you can use a `char` instead of a single character string in `payload.split("=")`. `payload.split'=')` would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) method on iterator which needs a "type" to know what it should collect into.

Also, you don't have to collect in order to extract the first token

```
let value = payload.split("=").nth(1).unwrap(); // you need to better error handling
println!("value is {:?}", value);
```

If you want to use your second example(inefficient), you can achieve it using turbofish syntax

```
let value = payload.split("=").collect::<Vec<&str>>()[1];
println!("value is {:?}", value);
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4632e97417950c0fdd6b64d8cb0d18f3)

Answer (score 0):

Your type annotation becomes invalid in second example. What you want is this:

```
let payload = "key1=value1";
let value: &str = payload.split("=").collect::<Vec<&str>>()[1];
println!("value is {:?}", value);
```

[rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4fd5ede4f9a5f1e02312abfea1c4cfd3)

Which can be simplified to this:

```
let payload = "key1=value1";
let value = payload.split("=").collect::<Vec<_>>()[1];
println!("value is {:?}", value);
```

The reason you need to be explicit is because an `Iterator<Item = &str>` can be collected into a dozen different collection types and the compiler can't guess at which one you want.